# Installed version not tested with active version of WooCommerce 4.4.1

Tags: cookies, path

I continue to get this error message on my wordpress front page:

Warning: Cookie paths cannot contain any of the following ',; \t\r\n\013\014' in /var/www/aveugle-shop.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php on line 1035

I can't figure out why this message is showing?
My hosting said that it was because they updated their php database (or something), and all i needed to do, was to run back their old one, by inserting a snippet into .htaccess file.

This worked for a day or two, and now it's showing again.
Do anyone know what the actual issue is, and how to fix it?

My woocommerce status also says this on a bunch of plugins, and i don't know if that's the fault:
Installed version not tested with active version of WooCommerce 4.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the correct solution but I got the same error just now.
It happened to me when I upgraded PHP from 7.2=>7.4.
It seems to originate somewhere from the database because I solved it by just importing the database again from my testserver, same database, same codebase but all of a sudden, it started to work after reimporting db... A cache issue maybe?